# Flutter upgrade to 2.5.3 causing deprecated issue in TextStyle color

Tags: flutter, textstyle, flutter-upgrade, buttoncolor

'buttonColor' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. No longer used by the framework,
please remove any reference to it. This feature was deprecated after v2.3.0-0.2.pre.

Below is the code causing the issue:

[image]

What should I change instead of buttonColor.
I tried with primary but could not find any reference in the official doc.

Thaks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there has been couple of breaking changes on buttons that you can see here --> https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons

In your case, the `themeData` reference has changed, you can see a detailed information, if you check the [ThemeData class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html).

You will be needing to use `buttonTheme` that is a [ButtonThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonThemeData-class.html) it like the following:

```
Theme.of(context).buttonTheme.colorScheme?.primary
```

Comment: Thank you so much @salih, I changed my code to Theme.of(context).buttonTheme.buttonColor as per the above suggestion and now getting error as: 

The getter 'buttonColor' isn't defined for the type 'ButtonThemeData'.

Comment: `color:Theme.of(context).buttonTheme.colorScheme?.primary`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextTheme`

**In your material app theme**

```
textTheme: TextTheme(
  button: TextStyle(
     fontSize: 18.0,
     color: "Your color",
     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
)
```

**In your code**

```
Text(
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.

Refer Button Changes [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons)

Refer [ButtonTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonTheme-class.html)

Refer [ButtonThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonThemeData-class.html)

```
TextButton(
  child: Text('Ok',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Theme.of(context).buttonTheme.colorScheme?.primary,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      )),
  onPressed: () {
    print('Button Pressed');
  },
),
```

your result screen-> [image]